# Heroku CLI error, can't access my django admin

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-cli

I have deployed my backend of webproject through Heroku CLI. To access my database, I went through herokuapp.com/admin, but I got Internal Servor Error.
So, I went to cmd to run `heroku run bash` command so that I can `run migrations`, but its showing this error:

[image: Error]

My frontend which is in Next.js is deployed on Vercel and it shows my website. Just that I want to access my database to add data, and Heroku is giving me Problems. My database is Postgres.

Answer (score -1):

The error indicates it requires an application name to run your command against. It usually happens when you have more than one application under a single account. Run these commands:

Get the list of all available apps by running:

```
heroku apps
```

Then from run your command by providing it an app from the app list generated from the command above:

```
heroku run base --app exampleapphere
```